# Detecting the browser language in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to get the browser language with Python Flask. I have tried to use:

`request.headers.get('languages')`

This however returns `None`.

I tried [whoer.net](http://whoer.net) and it returned `it-IT` for my browser language. How can I detect the browser language with Python Flask ?

Comment: Have you tried something like `print(request.headers)` to see what is in there?

Answer (score 15):

Check out Werkzeug's [LanguageAccept data structure](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.LanguageAccept), or just try something like this to get a best match:

```
supported_languages = ["en", "nl", "it"]
lang = request.accept_languages.best_match(supported_languages)
```

If you need more than that, then check out [Flask-Babel](https://python-babel.github.io/flask-babel/index.html).

Comment: Note that this doesn't match accept language `en-US` with supported_language `en`. If you're only accepting languages without regions, this can be solved by pre-processing the accept language header to drop the region: `werkzeug.datastructures.LanguageAccept([(al[0][0:2], al[1]) for al in request.accept_languages]).best_match(supported_languages)`

Comment: FYI, adding comment for future stumblers.  It looks like in 1.0.0 they fixed best_match now to match `en-US` with supported_language `en`
https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1651

Answer (score 0):

You should check `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet guides how to get the language from browser

```
@app.route('/link')
def mylink():
    print request.accept_languages
```

If the browser(say chrome) has multiple languages supported (see link for example), then the print statement will print all the languages supported by the browser. The first language listed is the preferred language of the user.

[chrome language settings example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAS7e.png)

Comment: The first language listed is not necessarily the preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar question: I needed to get the preferred language specified by the browser in `Accept-Language`. And not a fan of using Flask-Babel which hasn't been updated in years.

Ended up putting this together:

```py
"""
Return the preferred language code. In case of a draw return the first one only.
"""
def preferred_language(accept_language_header):
    accept_language_header = str(accept_language_header)
    return parse_and_sort_accept_language(accept_language_header)[0]['code']


"""
accept_language_header is a quality-value string.
  e.g. `en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,hu;q=0.6`
  No q implies 1. The top-level separator is the comma.
"""
def parse_and_sort_accept_language(accept_language_header):
    result = []
    languages_and_qualities = accept_language_header.split(',')

    for language_quality_pair in languages_and_qualities:
        if ';' in language_quality_pair:
            lang, quality = language_quality_pair.split(';')
            quality = float(quality[2:])
        else:
            lang = language_quality_pair
            # If the quality is not specified, set it to 1.0 (maximum quality)
            quality = 1.0

        # Add the parsed language-quality pair to the list
        result.append({
            'code': lang.split('-')[0], # ISO 639-1.
            'code_with_country': lang, # i.e. ISO 639-1 with ISO 3166-1 alpha-2.
            'quality': quality,
        })

    # Sort the parsed language-quality pairs by quality, in descending order
    result.sort(key=lambda x: x['quality'], reverse=True)
    return result
```

Then use like so:

```py
top_language = preferred_language(accept_language_header)
if top_language == 'fr':
    # this
// …
```